# Installing PyPy from source on low RAM devices

Tags: python, ram, pypy

I have a little bit of a wreck of a computer; 7+ years old, Intel Celeron @ 430 1.78 GHz, 448 MB of RAM, Lord only knows what motherboard graphics chip, etc. etc. running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit, and I want to install PyPy, but due to my Linux version I need to build it from source, [their install guide](http://pypy.org/download.html#building-from-source) basically suggested that I need much more RAM than I have...

I have tons of hard drive space, which could be used as a pagefile, is there any way to provide it with enough RAM to do this, (either up to ~1.6 GB and use their low RAM tweak in their guide, or 2-3 GB to do so without the tweak), by making it use a page file?

Also, don't worry about the speed of the process, as long as it doesn't exceed much more than 24 hours to build it...

Answer (score 1):

With only 400MB of RAM and a big pagefile, it's very likely to never finish in "just" one day (but I don't actually know).  You need to build on some other machine and then copy the binary, or take the binary we provide and then add the exact same version of all missing libraries...